# Update Eclipse menu radio state from code

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In the command handler for a radio state menu item, I prompt the user if they want to continue.  If they choose no, I need to reset the selected menu item back to the previous value.

I am using `HandlerUtil.updateRadioState(event.getCommand(), oldScope)` but the menu stays with the new value.

Any suggestions?

Command Handler

```java
@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    if (HandlerUtil.matchesRadioState(event))
        return null;

    String scope = event.getParameter(RadioState.PARAMETER_ID);

    if (MessageDialog.openConfirm(HandlerUtil.getActiveShell(event), "Confirm restart",
            "Switching source of Motors requires a restart.  Continue?")) {
        int connection = MotorDbPreferencesPage.DATABASE_ACCESS_LOCAL;
        if ("Cloud".compareToIgnoreCase(scope) == 0) {
            connection = MotorDbPreferencesPage.DATABASE_ACCESS_CLOUD;
        }
        Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore().setValue(MotorDbPreferencesPage.DATABASE_ACCESS, connection);
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().restart();
    } else {
        String oldScope = "Local";
        // switch it back to the way it was before the user selected it
        if ("Local".compareToIgnoreCase(scope) == 0) {
            oldScope = "Cloud";
        }
        HandlerUtil.updateRadioState(event.getCommand(), oldScope);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Command definition in plugin.xml

```xml
      <command
        id="com.client.eclipse.connection"
        name="Connection">
     <commandParameter
           id="org.eclipse.ui.commands.radioStateParameter"
           name="State"
           optional="false">
     </commandParameter>
     <state
           class="org.eclipse.ui.handlers.RadioState:Cloud"
           id="org.eclipse.ui.commands.radioState">
     </state>
  </command>
```

And the menu definition from plugin.xml

```xml
            <menu
              label="Connection">
           <command
                 commandId="com.client.eclipse.connection"
                 label="Local"
                 style="radio">
              <parameter
                    name="org.eclipse.ui.commands.radioStateParameter"
                    value="Local">
              </parameter>
           </command>
           <command
                 commandId="com.client.eclipse.connection"
                 label="Cloud"
                 style="radio">
              <parameter
                    name="org.eclipse.ui.commands.radioStateParameter"
                    value="Cloud">
              </parameter>
           </command>
        </menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your responsability to call

```
HandlerUtil.updateRadioState(event.getCommand(), scope);
```

to make the GUI displays the new state. Without calling it, the radio state won't change.

It means that in the case of user is aborting, don't call this method at all.